# Python O365 Authentication when Basic Authentication becomes deprecated

Tags: python, authentication, outlook

I have a script (that I did not write) that uses basic authentication to access email boxes online.  The script uses the following code:

```
from O365 import Connection

Connection.login(user, password)
```

It recently failed.  Doing a bit of research I got the following error:

```
'Basic Authentication for Outlook REST API is no longer supported...'
```

I found some information on `https://aka.ms/BasicAuthDeprecated`:

> Last year, we announced  that in November 2018, we will stop
> supporting  Basic Authentication in the Office 365   Outlook REST API
> v1.0 and this is a  follow up announcement to reiterate that we will
> be decommissioning Basic  Authentication in Outlook REST API v1.0 this
> month. This means that new or  existing apps will not be able to use
> Basic Authentication in v1.0 and Beta  versions of Outlook REST API
> starting December 2018.
>
> If you have been using Basic Authentication in Office 365 Outlook REST
> API  v1.0/Beta in your app, you should immediately transition to
> Microsoft Graph-  based Outlook REST APIs to continue accessing
> Exchange Online data.

Web authentication is not my strong suit and I'm not sure what I need to do here.  Looks like some sort of registration/token generation is required.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use OAuth for authenticating with O365 as BasicAuth is not supported anymore.

https://pypi.org/project/O365/#authentication has details on the Python library integration with OAuth.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply.  I found the instructions unclear.  Was able to register my app but was not clear how to get the token and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Circling back to this, so that others see this, the code example in the authentication section works:

```
from O365 import Account, FileSystemTokenBackend

credentials = ('id', 'secret')

# this will store the token under: "my_project_folder/my_folder/my_token.txt".
# you can pass strings to token_path or Path instances from pathlib
token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='my_folder', token_filename='my_token.txt')
account = Account(credentials, token_backend=token_backend)

# This account instance tokens will be stored on the token_backend configured before.
# You don't have to do anything more
# ...
```

When you run the code, it'll provide a url which you paste into a browser, and will provide a new url that you need to copy into code, which will authenticate and provide the token for further usage.